# Including php file in directory above WordPress installation

Tags: include

I'm having trouble including an external .php file into my WordPress theme.

**WordPress installation URL:** mydomainname.com/blog

**PHP File URL:** mydomainname.com/testing/assets/inc/analytics.php

I'm trying to include this PHP file from within header.php of my WordPress theme.

My line of code looks like this:

```
<?php include ( site_url() . '/testing/assets/inc/analytics.php' );  ?>
```

I've also tried variations of `PATH` and `ABSPATH` but I can't get it to work. Interestingly, when I change the `include` to `require_once` it breaks the site.

Please help me figure out what exactly I'm doing wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use file paths, not urls, so if mydomainname.com/blog is at /home/account/public_html/blog then your file is /home/account/public_html/testing/assets/inc/analytics.php.

I would recommend putting it into a one-off plugin though.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! This appears to be working. Unfortunately putting these files into a WordPress plugin is not an option for this project, but I will keep it in mind for the next time around.

Answer (score 0):

how about this one:

```
$path = dirname( ABSPATH );
include( $path . "/testing/assets/inc/analytics.php" );
```

Comment: Thanks for this awesome tip! This will keep things nicely in sync between my dev server and the live server. I'd give you an up-vote, but I need more rep points first.